# Problema com DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

Comprei um livro pra estudar Android, estou seguindo e tentando entender como funciona os componentes

Quando clico em um botão, eu preciso que abra um modal com o componente de data.

Estou usando o SDK 19 com Android 4.2, e quando em algum método disparado pelo click do botão, eu chamo um `showDialog`, ele me retorna

> The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated

parece que é algo relacionado pela versão do SDK que estou utilizando.

[image: SS]

Answer (score 1):

Essa informação nada tem a ver com a versão do SDK, mas sim com a utilização do método `showDialog` que se considera desatualizado.

Apartir da versão 3.0 (SDK 11) foi introduzida uma nova forma de utilizar os *"Dialogs"*, que se denomina de `DialogFragment`.

Em termos práticos nado o impede de continuar a utilizar o método `showDialog`, no entanto *"Android team"* recomenda que se utilize `DialogFragment`.

Como você está a dar os primeiros passos no Android recomendo que você ignore, para já, essa mensagem. Quando tiver mais experiência então comece a explorar os `Fragments`.

Se você não quiser seguir o meu conselho, veja [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker) como utilizar um `DatePicker`com `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta, porém não consigo ignoralo, pois ele não roda, me da erro ao acessar a activity. =/

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá?